# How can you showcase premium themes to clients without having to pre-purchase the theme?

Tags: themes

If you use a premium theme service (my skills lie more in coding than artwork), what is a good way to show clients examples of what themes are available to them, without sending them to the theme service site in the first place (i.e. without letting them see the original purchase price), but without having to purchase the theme upfront?

I know I can make a dummy WP site and use a theme switcher, but I don't want to purchase a bunch of themes that may never be used.

Comment: What about a Wordpress MU installation with different themes? Particularly for those themes that I have created myself, with extensive custom-post manipulation, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to display screenshots of the theme in action.  Many theme services allow you to view a "demo page" and see how the theme is presented - taking a screenshot of this page and passing it to your client is pretty much the same as presenting a stylized wireframe or stylistic mockup of the final design.  If it was an entirely custom site (i.e. you were responsible for the design as well), you'd likely present it this way *anyway* before investing any time in actual development.

Answer (score 2):

You could point them to actual sites that already use the themes you want to resell. Or you could contact the theme developers and explain your situation (I don't think it is uncommon), they could create a separate site where the themes are listed without prices (maybe even embeddable in your site).

Comment: Doh! Of course! Almost all of them have their own "in the wild" showcase section - why didn't I think of that? Fab idea, thanks

Comment: Oh I just noticed -- "Fab idea" wasn't meant to be a pun on your name ;)

Answer (score 0):

If theme has name in it mostly in the logo at demo sites, Your customer will be able to get the price from Google anyways.
So taking screenshots won't be enough too, take screenshots and tweek the logo and text whereever it is about theme, then you can actually hide the original theme and price from client.